Bert finetuning for binary classification with special tokens evaluates badly
I'm fine tuning a BERT model for binary classifcation, before the training process starts I add some tokens which help with explainability on the task, but I'm getting really bad scores on the evaluation process. I'm relatively new to fine tuning bert models and I'm thinking I've messed something up in my training or evaluation function of the model, or the tokens have not been added properly. The self.model is a BertForSequenceClassification with no additional layers added to it. The tokenizer is not trained, both model and tokenizer are base bert.
This is the code I'm using for adding tokens and training the model:
def add_tokens(self):
        try:
            logger.print_and_log("Adding Extra Tokens ...", "green")
            self.tokenizer.add_tokens(self.extra_tokens, special_tokens = True)
            self.model.resize_token_embeddings(len(self.tokenizer))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.print_and_log("Error: " + str(e), "red")

    def train(self, epochs=3):
        try:
            logger.log("Training Model ...")
            if (self.extra_tokens):
                self.add_tokens()
            encodings = self.tokenizer(self.train_data, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
            dataset = TensorDataset(encodings['input_ids'], encodings['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(self.train_labels))
            dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, sampler=RandomSampler(dataset), batch_size=8)
            optimizer = Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)
            loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

            self.model.train()
            for epoch in range(epochs):
                logger.print_and_log("Epoch: " + str(epoch), "green")
                for batch in tqdm.tqdm(dataloader):
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    input_ids, attention_mask, labels = batch
                    input_ids = input_ids.to(self.device)
                    attention_mask = attention_mask.to(self.device)
                    labels = labels.to(self.device)
                    outputs = self.model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
                    loss = loss_fn(outputs.logits, labels)
                    outputs = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=1).cpu().detach().numpy()
                    loss.backward()
                    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.model.parameters(), 1.0)
                    optimizer.step()
            logger.log("Training Complete for " + self.model_name + ".")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.print_and_log("Error: " + str(e), "red")

I tried training the model with different epochs, batch sizes and different splits on the data but that didn't seem to work which reaffirms my suspicion that I have made a mistake possibly on the layout of the code.
